# Search Overflow

Tags: bug, search

Usually when searching, the search results returns the question title and two or three lines of preview from the post itself bolding the words being searched for. All good so far.

However when searching for "Stack Overflow"... well, [see for yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Stack%20Overflow%22):

> [image]

Wall of text, right there in the results. More than one.

I could not reproduce this overflow with any other search terms, including just ["stackoverflow"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22stackoverflow%22).

It happens both on Meta and the main site.

Hidden Easter Egg, or a nasty bug?

Comment: [Its not a bug its a feature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/234170/1947286)

Comment: @animuson nice one, cheers! :)

Comment: because experts-exchange